# No DNS after upgrade-manager upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, dns, dist-upgrade, resolvconf

I upgraded a Ubuntu Zesty to Artufl over SSH using `upgrade-manager`. All went well except for DNS. Name resolution fails, including `ping`. I still have an IP and I can SSH into it after reboot, but that may be old lease information. I understand systemd now handles resolver duties.

The tail of my `dmeg` is showing failed DHCP audits.

```
[    8.397015] audit: type=1400 audit(1515252083.757:46): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" name="/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.11" pid=951 comm="nm-dhcp-helper" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    8.434243] audit: type=1400 audit(1515252083.794:47): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" name="/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.11" pid=955 comm="nm-dhcp-helper" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` has the following. I don't have other Ubuntu machines so I am not sure if this is expected under systemd.

```
[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=yes
#MulticastDNS=yes
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=udp
```

Searching for the AppArmor failure is returning 0 hits. I suspect that has a lot to do with the troubles, and I was surprised Google returned 0 results.

There are no `apparmor-profile.dhclient` files in `/usr` or `/etc` as discussed at [Ubuntu Issue 1417658](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1417658), so it is a dead end. I also tried uncommenting `#DNS=` and setting it to `DNS=yes` in `resolved.conf` but that did not fix the issue.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

---

> Comment] What is the output of `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`

```
$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov 29  2016 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

---

Here are some Ubuntu bug reports for the problems:

- [Cannot resolve DNS in artful daily](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1712283)

  - `rm /etc/resolv.conf` and `ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` did not help
- [resolvconf not correctly configured after update from 17.04 to 17.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1725840)

  - `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` did not help
  - `ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` followed by `systemctl restart resolvconf` did not help
  - `apt install resolvconf` did not help
- [DNS not working after upgrade 17.04 to 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966870/dns-not-working-after-upgrade-17-04-to-17-10)

  - `rm /etc/resolv.conf` followed by `ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` did not help
  - `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` did not help

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: `ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Thanks @GAD3R. That did not help. I'm going to install Fedora 27. That should fix the problem once and for all. It is kind of surreal... five years ago most of my Linux machines were Ubuntu. I don't think I have any Ubuntu machines left because of problems like this.